# Bash scripts with tmux to launch a 4-paned window

Tags: bash, tmux

Can anyone help explain what's going on with `tmux`, `bash`, and `exec`? I'm trying to set up a tmux session with a 4-pane window. Ideally, I want to run a command in 3 of the panes: e.g. a Ruby Thin server and a couple of Ruby daemons. This is what I have so far:

`~/.bin/tmux-foo`:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux new-session -d -s foo 'exec pfoo "bundle exec thin start"'
tmux rename-window 'Foo'
tmux select-window -t foo:0
tmux split-window -h 'exec pfoo "bundle exec compass watch"'
tmux split-window -v -t 0 'exec pfoo "rake ts:start"'
tmux split-window -v -t 1 'exec pfoo'
tmux -2 attach-session -t foo
```

`~/.bin/pfoo`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/projects/foo
rvm use ree

# here I want to execute command1 2 3 or 4...

exec $SHELL
```

It all works... but when I `ctlr-c` in the first pane that is running the thin server, it stops the thin server and returns to the shell. However, the command is not in the history; i.e. if I hit the up key I don't get the `bundle exec thin start` command... I get some other command from my bash history. I'm wondering if there's any way to arrange these scripts so that I get the commands in the bash history.

Also... I've tried many combinations of `exec`, `exec $SHELL -s ...`, and `exec $SHELL -s ... -I` and I'm not quite sure what is going on...

Can anyone help explain the general idea of what is going on with `tmux` and `bash` and `exec` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I wanted something like this:

```
tmux splitw -t 'foo':2
tmux send-keys -t 'foo':2 'rvm use ree' C-m
tmux send-keys -t 'foo':2 'bundle exec compass watch
```

`send-keys` with `C-m` will execute the command in the window/pane and will keep it in the history.

Answer (score 0):

The commands are not in the shell's history simply because you started the shell *after* running those commands. Ctrl-C doesn't *return* to a shell; it causes `pfoo` to start a new one (the `exec $SHELL` line).

Comment: Ah... makes sense. Do you know of any way to get the command into the history. Is there a way to `exec $SHELL` with the command?

Comment: @Aaron: 1) Append it to the history file (`echo "$@" >> ~/.bash_history`) before exec'ing. 2) No.